# Cart Throb - live rates and disable shipping

Tags: cartthrob

I am running CartThrob and using Live shipping rates.  The problem I have run into is if I have one product in the cart and I have Shipping Disabled for that product the live rates plugin is still showing shipping options.

How do others get around this?

CartThrob 2.2.2
EE 2.5.3

```
Shipping: <select name="shipping_option">
{exp:cartthrob:get_shipping_options}
    <option value="{rate_short_name}" {selected}>{rate_title} - {price}</option>
{/exp:cartthrob:get_shipping_options}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to wrap your code for the live rates in a cart_info tag and then check the value of shipping first, e.g.

```
 {exp:cartthrob:cart_info}
   {if cart_shipping>0}
       live rates code here
   {/if}
 {/exp:cartthrob:cart_info}
```